# Build 2D array using append

Tags: python, list, append

Python: I would like to read set of data

```
(category, value): (0, 1) (0, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4)
```

To an array as

```
[[1, 2],[3, 4]]
```

Since max number of category is unknown, I would like to create 2D-array dynamically using "append" method.

I wrote a sample code:

```
data = []
data.append([])

data[0].append(1)
data[0].append(2)

try:
  print (data[1])
except IndexError:
  data.append([])
finally:
  data[1].append(3)
  data[1].append(4)

print(data)
```

But, I understand that the code is really ugly because I am using "print" to check the access to `data[1]`.

Is there any more beautiful solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do this easily along with a [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter).

```
>>> l = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
>>> i = iter(l)
>>> [[x[1],y[1]] for x,y in zip(i,i)]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

The algorithm here is to iterate over the list of tuples in pairs. This is where `iter` comes to use. `iter` creates an iterator that is consumed by the `zip` function. We then read the tuples into the list comprehension and add only the required two numbers, which is the second indices.

See [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-in-python-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-us) for more details about them.

Comment: Hello sir, I have created room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230139/talkwithsir  for chat now, I am IST timings in case I slept before you join please forgive me :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

a = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
g = itertools.groupby(a, key=lambda x: x[0])
g = [list(i[1]) for i in g]
```